# Boolean for each question with array list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, boolean

one var with multiples "selected" question relates to "employee". 
When open the system will show up all question, whatever I pressed the button will show me an employee and I will select one (ex: Brian for the first question) and will select "positive". 
When I click on my second question, Brian is already selected. HERE is my problem. 
Should be select only in one question and is making flag for all question.

anything wrong with the boolean?

```
var resultHandler = function(){
    currentQuestion = this;
    $('#details-name').text(currentQuestion.question);
    $('#projectPopUp').show();
};


var cancel = function() {
    //do nothing for now
}


var commenthandler = function() {
    var value = $("#" + this.id + "-comment").val();
    this.comments = value;
    $("#" + this.id + "-comment").val(value);
};


var names = [];

// bt select ppl    
var nameList = function (){

    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        var name = employees[i];

        var id = i;
        var data = {
            id: 'e' +id,
            name: name
        };

        names.push(data);

        $('#detailsgrid tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#popupPersonTemplate tbody", data));
        $("#" + data.id + "-status").text('Select');
        $("#" + data.id + "-status").click(statusHandler.bind(data));
    }

};


var statusHandler = function(){

    var previousResult = this.inspectionResult;
    var answerIndex = answers.indexOf(previousResult);
    /** -1 is if the answer is not found if not found defaults to first answer
     * else it gets the next answer
     */
    console.log('Answer Index: ' + answerIndex);
    if (answerIndex == -1) {
        console.log('Answer index is -1');
        answerIndex = 0;
        this.active = 'false';
        updateActiveStatus(this);

    } else {
        answerIndex = (answerIndex + 1) % answers.length;
    }

    var currentResult = answers[answerIndex];
    this.inspectionResult = currentResult;

    $("#" + this.id + "-status").text(currentResult);
    // commentvisibilitymanager(this);

};


var buildQuestionnaire = function(){
    parseInitialDataHolder();

    for (var i = 0; i < ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS.length; i++){
        var id = ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].code;
        if (id && typeof id != 'undefined'){
            id = id.replace('.', '-');
        };
        var data = {
            id: id,
            question: ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].question,
            inspectionResult: "", //defaultResults
            employee_results: [],
            active: true
        };

        var initialdata = initialdataholder[id];
        if(initialdata) {
            data = initialdata;
        }
        dataholder.push(data);

        if (typeof ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].header == 'undefined') {
            $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#rowTemplate tbody", data));
            $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text(data.inspectionResult || 'Select');
            $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").click(resultHandler.bind(data));
            updateActiveStatus(data);
            commentvisibilitymanager(data);
        }
        else {
            $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#sectionRowTemplate tbody", data));
        }
    }

}

//to close the popup
var closePopup = function() {
    $('#projectPopUp').hide();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    buildQuestionnaire();
    nameList();
});
```

Comment: Can you limit the code to what's important? That's a lot of code to look through

Comment: please use an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: still not working

Comment: @paulo.gomes Please create a code snippet with the least amount of code that still reproduces your problem and describe the result you are expecting. That makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: I'm explaining the description! should select once flag for each question but when is select in one question, is populated for all question.